# GCP Cloud Build suddenly cannot fetch npm package from Github Package

Tags: github, npm, yarnpkg, google-cloud-build, github-package-registry

I've my working Cloud Build fetching private npm package from Github.

I've already setup the .yarnrc npmRegistryScopes and auth token.

It worked for the whole day.
Then suddenly it stopped working and gave me this in the Cloud Build yarn install step.

```
YN0035: │ @myorg/mypackage@npm:0.3.3::__archiveUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fnpm.pkg.github.com%2Fdownload%2F%40myorg%2Fmypackage%2F0.3.3%2F02814855b510d459819aba67f3727764aaf46a06: The remote server failed to provide the requested resource
➤ YN0035: │   Response Code: 403 (Forbidden)
➤ YN0035: │   Request Method: GET
➤ YN0035: │   Request URL: https://npm.pkg.github.com/download/@myorg/mypackage/0.3.3/02814855b510d459819aba67f3727764aaf46a06
```

I've no idea what happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Oh dear, I spent 3 hours to figure it out, It is the billing issue.